# Remove viewed Files from PC using IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ihttphandler

Is there any way to remove the viewed Documents/Images from PC with apsx? In my IHttpHandler i tried:

```
context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

In Firefox the temp Files are saved in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\jwhjrpy1.default\cache2\entries

I don't want to delete everything, but only the files that are opened with the aspx application.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There is no way to ensure that a file you have sent to a client via HTTP isn't saved some how, by setting cache headers as you are, you are simply telling the browser that it should not server up cached versions of these resources, it should make a fresh request to the server each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent saving content on the client. Even if you don't cache the file, it is still possible to download the file, and most browsers do this automatically.

Then the file is outside the control of the browser.

Comment: With the Application users can see sensitive Data (for example own  medical reports) but Data shouldn't stay stored in PC. So I thought maybe there is a solutions for this

Comment: Don't make something available if you don't want it to get spread. The user can even make a screenshot of it.

Comment: The users should be able to store data, but my Application shouldn't store anything automatically

Comment: That is the uncontrollable part of the web, once you sent it, you can't control it. Maybe a little using DRM solutions, but those have proven useless too.